# How to check that user is logged out from Facebook or the token is expired

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a Fragment which I am calling in my MainActivity OnCreate method.  In  this fragment I am asking user to log in the face book. My code goes like this:

```
 public class FbLogin extends Fragment {
        private AccessToken accessToken;
        private Profile profile;
        private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
        static AccessTokenTracker tracker;
        private ProfilePictureView profilepic;
        LoginButton loginButton;
        LoginPrefrence loginPrefrence ;


        private CallbackManager mcallbackManager;

        private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mcallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                getFbData(profile);


                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                Log.d("Amc", graphResponse.toString());


                                try {
                                    String id = object.getString("id");
                                    String name = object.getString("name");
                                  //  String email = object.getString("email");
                                    String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                    profilepic.setProfileId(object.getString("id"));

                                  //if want to make it round
                                    /*
                                    profileImageView = ((ImageView)faceBookProfilePictureView.getChildAt(0));
                                bitmap  = ((BitmapDrawable)profileImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                  circular.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                  profilepic.getChildAt(0);
                                     */



                                   // String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                  // String Uri1 =(object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url"));
                                    Log.d("Amc2",""+id + ", " + name + ", " +""+ ""+ ", " + gender + ", " );
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.d("Amc2",""+e.toString());
                                }



                            }


                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            }

        };

        public FbLogin() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            mcallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            tracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

                }
            };
            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                    getFbData(newProfile);

                }
            };
            tracker.startTracking();
            profileTracker.startTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            tracker.stopTracking();
            profileTracker.stopTracking();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            profileTracker.stopTracking();
            tracker.stopTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            tracker.stopTracking();
            profileTracker.stopTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fb_login, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


            profilepic = (ProfilePictureView)view.findViewById(R.id.pf_view);
            loginPrefrence = new LoginPrefrence(getActivity());
            loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email","user_birthday"));
            loginButton.setFragment(this);
            loginButton.registerCallback(mcallbackManager, mcallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            mcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        public void getFbData(Profile prof) {

            if (prof != null) {

                Log.d("Facebook", prof.getFirstName());
                Log.d("Facebook", prof.getName());
                Log.d("Facebook", prof.getId().toString());

            }

        }



    }
```

this is a simple facebook login code. But I want to do following

1. How to check in the MianActivity if the User is still log in
2. How can I access Token , and what is the main and real usage of token and How to track if it is expired
3. which method is called when use will click the log out button in my app.

Please help me , I have tried every thing but nothing really is helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the current access token with following lines of code

```
private Boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        //user is logged in already
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I access it in the main activity ?

Comment: it is an static way you can access it from anywhere after initializing the facebook sdk

Comment: in my fragment it is saying me can not resolve getCurrentAccesToekn

Comment: try to use it at the last of `onCreate()` method it will work

Comment: please clear me one point , I am login in one fragment , would using this line of code that you suggested would fetch out the token in any activity ?

Comment: also I want to ask , is there any thing required in this section to tell the app that user is loged out

tracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

                }
            };

Comment: yes in any activity which have facebook sdk initialized

Comment: No you can leave that section blank for now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82468/discussion-between-stacy-queen-and-gopal-singh-sirvi).